# SQL Server failover

Tags: sql-server

I have an in-house server running multiple applications which uses MSSQL as a DB. I have two public IPs. I have purchased a failover service from Azure, so when my one ISP goes down, it points the traffic to another. The problem is when one ISP goes down my apps hosted on IIS works properly, SQL Server doesn't work because we can define only one IP on Web.config. Is there any workaround? So that when one ISP fails my SQL Server also switches to active ISP IP?

Comment: Is the database server on Azure or on premises? What failover service are you using? Can you not use dynamic DNS?

Comment: Hi, my Servers are on-premise. We are using Azure traffic manager for failover. I don't know how Dyn DNS will help in this case? Please assist if you have any solution using Dyn DNS.

Comment: Azure Traffic Manager uses DNS as I understand it. So just use that domain name instead of an IP address. The connection string can (and should) use a domain name not an IP address

Comment: Hi mate, Thanks for replying. I will ask my dev team to modify the file and add the domain name and check, will revert you with the result.

Comment: @Charlieface Hey mate, it worked. Thanks a lot. I have been facing this problem for the last 6 months. You're a lifesaver. Thanks again. Btw how can mark your reply as an answer for this post?

Answer (score 4):

Azure Traffic Manager uses DNS as the failover mechanism.

**So just use that domain name in your SQL connection string, instead of an IP address.** The connection string can (and should) use a domain name not an IP address